# Ruby on Rails current_user not recognized in css.erb

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I changed my pages.scss extension to pages.scss.erb but if i try(BTW I use devise):

```
 <% if current_user.admin == true%>
    body { background-color: white}
 <% else %>
    body { background-color: black}
 <% end %>
```

it gives me an error :
Showing /app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
undefined local variable or method `current_user` for #<#:0x0000000e9e5be8>

but if I try User.current instead of current_user it doesn't give me an error but code doesn't work.... I tried using(I cycled between the values of a):

```
    <% a = true %>
    <% if a == true%>
       body { background-color: white}
     <% else %>
        body { background-color: black}
     <% end %>
```

and it worked

Comment: Where is your `current_user` method defined? In helper, in controller, or somewhere else?

Comment: `current_user` should not be defined in the model. However it's defined, it should be a concern of controllers. I think you need to review how you are handling authentication in general.

Comment: @TomLord ok then how do I define it in the applications controller

Comment: @TomLord oh sorry I forgot I was using devise

Comment: Serving dynamic stylesheets is usually a bad idea, because Rails likes to precompile its assets. It would be much easier to add an `admin` class to the `body` tag (depending on the current user's role) and set different background colors for `body { ... }` and `body.admin { ... }`

Comment: @Stefan I've tried that and it doesn't work

Comment: @J.Foe could you show your attempt? Maybe we can help to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Result that you want to achieve assumes precompiling css on each request. Dynamic assets precompilation is normal for development environment to speed up your development process. However in production or staging environments assets are usually compiled once during deploy time (rake assets:precompile). Assets are not more than static and in production usually served by, for example, nginx.

So if you really want some dynamic CSS, depending on user's role, consider putting it to the layout. From there you will be able to use helper methods and controller variables.

```
<style type="text/css">  
  <% if current_user.admin == true %>
    body { background-color: white }
  <% else %>
    body { background-color: black }
  <% end %>
</style>
```

**Or, much better way, define CSS-classes for admin and plain user in your `.css` files, and then, in your `.html.erb` templates use them depending on your `current_user`.**

> I tried using (I cycled between the values of a):
>
> ```
> <% a = true %>
> <% if a == true%>
>   body { background-color: white }
> <% else %>
>   body { background-color: black }
> <% end %>
> ```
>
> and it worked

It worked because Rails asset pipeline supports embedded ruby in general, but it is assumed that it will be invoked once, during compilation. And it shouldn't be related to request and it's environment.